# What is the parameter "index" in Pandas.DataFrame.rename method?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rename, col

Pandas DataFrame has a rename method which takes a parameter named "index."
I don't understand the description of the parameter in the documentation:
[DataFrame.rename](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html)

Specifically, I'm using it like the example on the documentation web page:

```
df.rename(index=str, columns={"A": "a", "B": "c"})
```

I understand the result, but I don't understand why we set `index=str`.

What is the `index` parameter used for?
Why does the example set `index=str`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The *index* parameter is used to rename index, take *df* from the example:

```
df.index
# RangeIndex(start=0, stop=3, step=1)

df.rename(index=str).index                               # converts index from int to str
# Index(['0', '1', '2'], dtype='object')
```

This works because in the *rename* function, you can also pass functions to *index* and *columns* parameter which will be applied to each element in the index and columns. Here *str* acts as a function and convert every index from *int* to *str* object.

---

Another example:

```
df.rename(index=lambda x: x*2).index
# Int64Index([0, 2, 4], dtype='int64')
```

Comment: Ok, but why do we need to convert each element in index to a `str` when I want to rename a column?  Why doesn't `df.rename(columns={"A": "a", "B": "c"})` this work?

Comment: I believe the docs is trying to show you how to use the *index* parameter, (may not be a clear way though), as `df.rename(columns={"A": "a", "B": "c"})` should work jus fine.

Comment: @user3731622 The way you show `rename()` in your comments does in fact work. You don't need to specify index, it's optional.

Comment: ok, thanks.  I must have had another issue b/c I thought I tried it but it didn't work.  `df.rename(columns={"A": "a", "B": "c"})` does work.